# Unable to fully uninstall Vim from Monterey

Tags: terminal, homebrew, vi

I installed Vim using Homebrew, but I need to uninstall it.

I ran `brew uninstall vim`, but for some reason I'm still able to launch vim from the Terminal. Even after trying to uninstall, `vim --version` shows that I have v8.2 installed and provides a list of included features in my install.

`whereisvim` gives me `usr/bin/vim` and `usr/share/man/man1/vim.1` but I'm unable to delete the files from these directories. I've also checked in the Applications folder and the `~/Library` directories but there aren't any files related to Vim.

I'm new to this so any input would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You could do `alias vim=:` so that executing `vim` does nothing when invoked from the Terminal.

Answer (score 1):

`/usr/bin/vim` is the Apple supplied version.

For instance on my Ventura system:

```
% /usr/bin/vim --version
VIM - Vi IMproved 9.0 (2022 Jun 28, compiled Dec 16 2022 23:29:16)
macOS version - arm64
Included patches: 1-981
Compiled by root@apple.com
.
etc, etc...
```

reports `Compiled by root@apple.com`. It would be worthwhile verifying who built your remaining version. Note this cannot be uninstalled as it's part of the secure system volume.

Comment: Thank you for the help!

Answer (score 0):

#### That’s the default VIM included with macOS

`/usr/bin/vim` is the version of VIM that ships  with macOS.  In fact, you can browse https://opensource.apple.com/releases/ and scroll down to find Apple’s [VIM project on GitHub](https://github.com/apple-oss-distributions/vim/tree/vim-136)

If you used `brew uninstall vim` then you’ve removed the VIM installed via said method.

Anything in `/usr/bin` is on the *read only* portion of your system and thusly, you cannot delete anything from there.

Comment: Ah! I see I see thank you for the help!